# Retrieve Cookie in MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I created a JavaScript function which fire under `document.ready`

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

When I try to retrieve this cookie from MVC controller...

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cname"].Value
```

I get a null value and shows error. How do I get this cookie's value?

**updates of the code.** no idea why it suddenly works. i don't remembered i change any of the codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        setCookie('cname','computername',999);

});
```

**controller**

```
var computername=HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cname"].Value
```

**script file**

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
```

}

Comment: which error do u get ?

Comment: no errors.But somehow i managed to get it worked. sometimes i donno why it works and why it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

your code is working fine , but i think you forget to write `javascript` code in the view inside `scripts section`

```
@section scripts
{
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           setCookie("test", "test", 10);
       });

       function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
           var d = new Date();
           d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
           var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
           document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
       }
</script> 
}
```

Comment: i updated my content in my post. any i got it work somehow. no idea what i  had changed.it just works out of sudden. could be some typo at some where.
thanks